pydub не может найти мой файл
я пытаюсь воспроизвести wav файл через pydub и sounddevice. этот код должен воспроизводить звук взад или вперед в зависимости от выбора:
from pydub import AudioSegment
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np


sound = AudioSegment.from_file(r"test.wav")

sound_arr = np.array(sound.get_array_of_samples())

def play_sound(direction):
    if direction == "forward":
        sd.play(sound_arr, blocking=True)
    elif direction == "back":
        reversed_sound_arr = np.flipud(sound_arr)
        sd.play(reversed_sound_arr, blocking=True)
    else:
        print("Некорректное направление воспроизведения")

while True:
    direction = input("Введите направление воспроизведения (forward/back): ")
    play_sound(direction)

скрипт находится по пути C:\Users\User\Desktop\programming\testings.py, файл называется test.wav и находится в той же папке.
когда я запускаю скрипт выдается ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\programming\testings.py", line 6, in <module>
    sound = AudioSegment.from_file(r"test.wav")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 651, in from_file
    file, close_file = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(file, 'rb', tempfile=False)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 60, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.wav'

я пробовал указывать полный путь к файлу но он все равно не находится.
